# Need to replace HTML single-quote entity in MySQL

Tags: mysql, html, replace, entity

I currently have the following MySQL statement to replace the HTML entity for a single quote with an actual single quote:

```
update photo_galleries replace(title, '&#39;', '\'');
```

This statement returns an error. I have tried adding additional backslashes, but this does not help at all. I want to run this command using pure SQL (no PHP, etc.). Any suggestions are welcome and appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a valid SQL query, you were probably looking for:

```
UPDATE photo_galleries
SET title = REPLACE(title, '&#39;', '\'');
```

Comment: That is exactly what I meant - I accidentally excised the missing part. Oops - and thanks!

Comment: No, works great. I previously had unintentionally removed the "SET title = " from the statement and did not notice.

Comment: @modulaaron: You may want to mark the answer as accepted, by clicking on the green tick, if it was helpful. And welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 2):

Your `UPDATE` statement is invalid. You may want to try:

```
UPDATE photo_galleries SET title = REPLACE(title, '&#39;', '\'');
```

The `REPLACE()` function works correctly:

```
SELECT REPLACE('hello=&#39;test&#39;', '&#39;', '\'') AS output;
+--------------+
| output       |
+--------------+
| hello='test' | 
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```